# Sqlalchemy InvalidRequestError while Manually triggering Dags from Airflow 2.6.0

Tags: airflow

I am running airflow with the following configurations

**Airflow Version** : 2.6.0

**Python version**: 3.9

**SQLAlchemy**: 1.4.47

Executor : kubernetes
K8s version : v1.20.5
helm version: v3.6.3

Postgres Version:  PostgreSQL 11.12 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

I am able to create the airflow instance and dags are parsing by the scheduler but whenever I am triggering a manual run from the console I am getting the below error.

```
usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:366 DeprecationWarning: The auth_backend option in [api] has been renamed to auth_backends - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:389 DeprecationWarning: The auth_backend option in [api] has been renamed to auth_backends - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py:1001 DeprecationWarning: The namespace option in [kubernetes] has been moved to the namespace option in [kubernetes_executor] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snowflake/connector/options.py:108 UserWarning: You have an incompatible version of 'pyarrow' installed (9.0.0), please install a version that adheres to: 'pyarrow<10.1.0,>=10.0.1; extra == "pandas"'
[2023-05-19T18:18:57.042+0000] {dagbag.py:541} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/util/airflow-log-cleanup.py
[2023-05-19T18:18:57.336+0000] {airflow-log-cleanup.py:36} INFO - ENABLE_DELETE_CHILD_LOG  {{ var.value.get("airflow_log_cleanup__enable_delete_child_log", "False") }}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 48, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py", line 51, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 112, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 405, in task_run
    ti, _ = _get_ti(task, args.map_index, exec_date_or_run_id=args.execution_date_or_run_id, pool=args.pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 169, in _get_ti
    dag_run, dr_created = _get_dag_run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 108, in _get_dag_run
    dag_run = dag.get_dagrun(run_id=exec_date_or_run_id, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1403, in get_dagrun
    query = session.query(DagRun)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2163, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 180, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 187, in _set_entities
    self._raw_columns = [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 188, in <listcomp>
    coercions.expect(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 186, in expect
    insp._post_inspect
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1184, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2199, in _post_inspect
    self._check_configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1941, in _check_configure
    _configure_registries({self.registry}, cascade=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3527, in _configure_registries
    _do_configure_registries(registries, cascade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3566, in _do_configure_registries
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1958, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 231, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2150, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2245, in _process_dependent_arguments
    self.target = self.entity.persist_selectable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1113, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2112, in entity
    argument = self._clsregistry_resolve_name(self.argument)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/clsregistry.py", line 393, in _resolve_name
    rval = d[token]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 746, in __missing__
    self[key] = val = self.creator(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/clsregistry.py", line 352, in _access_cls
    return _determine_container(key, decl_class_registry[key])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/clsregistry.py", line 313, in _determine_container
    value = value.attempt_get([], key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/clsregistry.py", line 144, in attempt_get
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Multiple classes found for path "DagRun" in the registry of this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path.
```

I was wondering if this related to version conflicts or any other issue ? I tried to check the constraints as well but could not find anything.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.0/constraints-3.9.txt

The task pods are erring out with the above error.

Any suggestions to debug this issue is highly welcome.

Thanks in advance.